# GCCcore error compiling Python 3.8.2 with Easybuild

Tags: python, build, centos7, build-automation, build-system

I am trying to compile and install `Python 3.8.2` using Easybuild software and I get this error.

```
gcc: error: -fuse-linker-plugin is not supported in this configuration
ln: failed to access libpython3.8.so.1.0: No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [libpython3.8.so] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/alireza/deleteme/new/build/Python/3.8.2/GCCcore-9.2.0/Python-3.8.2'
make[2]: *** [build_all_generate_profile] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/alireza/deleteme/new/build/Python/3.8.2/GCCcore-9.2.0/Python-3.8.2'
make[1]: *** [profile-gen-stamp] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/alireza/deleteme/new/build/Python/3.8.2/GCCcore-9.2.0/Python-3.8.2'
make: *** [profile-run-stamp] Error 2
 (at easybuild/software/EasyBuild/4.2.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easybuild/tools/run.py:533 in parse_cmd_output)
```

The complete log file can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/alirezaghavaminia/03e560356eec6e553fd52548d91a9b22).

I tried `GCCcore 9.3.0` and `GCCcore 9.2.0`.The manual of Gcc shows that it supports this flag, and compiling on another machine with this configuration has worked before. I don't know what is wrong here. 
Do you have any suggestions for me?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I am having the exact same error, has the issue been resolved?!

Comment: See also https://github.com/easybuilders/easybuild-easyconfigs/issues/10805